# get the index of an array for a patrticular value

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, search

```
ArrayIndex|Value|Running total
-------------------------------
   0      |  6  | 6
   1      |  1  | 7
   2      |  6  | 13
   3      |  2  | 15
I:array index
V:value
R:Running total
```

I need to select the appropriate index for the given running total , for example
12 is the given running total ,so the appropriate index is 2,  i will put my code block bellow its not working i have tried using break; after the if statement as well , anyone one can help me solve this please:)

```
int running_total = 0;
boolean v=false;
    for(int x=0;x<=array.length;x++)
        {
        running_total+=array[x];
        if(running_total>=12)
            {
            if(v==false)
                {
                v= true;
                othermethods(x);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: use `x<array.length` instead of `x<=` and avoid using undeclarative variables.. and in `if(v == false)` replace it with `if(!v)` and avoid using too if! you can only use `if(running_total >= 12 && !v)`

Comment: Is it a 3 dimensional array of just a `String[]` array with elements composed as `I|V|R` ?

Comment: What @nachokk suggests is correct. Indices in Java go from 0 to n - 1, where n is the length of an array.

Answer (score 1):

The only error in your method is that you let `x` run to `array.length` inclusive, causing a crash with `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException` when the total is less than 12.

Change your code to

```
for(int x=0 ; x < array.length ; x++) {
    ...
}
```

to avoid the crash.

Another "point for style" is that instead of writing `v==false` it is more conventional to write `!v`. Finally, since the intent is to stop calling `othermethods(x)` after finding the first index where the running total satisfies the condition, you can rewrite the loop with a `break` instead of a boolean variable:

```
for(int x=0 ; x < array.length ; x++) {
    running_total+=array[x];
    if(running_total >= 12) {
        othermethods(x);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: and using only an if! `if(something){ if(otherThing){//some code} } }` just use `if(something && otherThing)`

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int x=0;x<array.length;x++)
```

length runs from `0` to `n - 1`, so change the `<=` in the loop to `<`

Answer (score 0):

```
int running_total = 0;
int x = 0;
for(x=0; x<array.length, running_total < 12; x++){
running_total += array[i];
}

//required index is x+1
```