# add the element of array until it reaches a value , when the value is reached find the index

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, math

I am trying to add the elements of an array until it reaches given value x , when the value is reached tit should return the appropriate index of that array

```
ArrayIndex|Value|Running total
-------------------------------
   0      |  6  | 6
   1      |  1  | 7
   2      |  6  | 13
   3      |  2  | 15
```

if the given value x is 14 it should return the index 3, or if the given value is 8 it should return 2 , how do i do it ? is there any algorithm i can use ?

```
int given_number = 7;
int running_total =0;
for(int x=0;x<array.length;x++)
{
     running_total+=array[x];
     if(given_number>=running_total)
     {
          //only allow once 
          setThredhold(x);//calling a mehod



     }
```

Comment: `return[x]` is gibberish, try `return x`. Otherwise, the code you gave is clearly the best algorithm. Linear time and constant space, I don't see a way anyone could do better.

Comment: return[x] doesn't compile. You need to rethink this line: if (givenNumber >= runningTotal) { What is supposed to be happening, and what are you actually checking?

Comment: Also, assuming the proper "return x;" line, "break;" is unreachable code, and you'll get a compile error for that too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get the index of an array for a patrticular value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445605/get-the-index-of-an-array-for-a-patrticular-value)

Comment: also that `break` statement is redundant after a `return` statement.

Comment: By the way, you want to handle the case where the given number is bigger than the sum of the entire list. Return a default value (either -1 or array.length-1 seem reasonable) after the for loop.

Comment: duplicate?:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445605/get-the-index-of-an-array-for-a-patrticular-value

Comment: yes it is a duplicate as that question was not clear , and i have fixed the return x , and i can't use the break as it exits the program

Comment: You can't use break because it never reaches the break statement it will exit the method before it reaches it. Make sure you are in a method also.... when you are returning stuff.

Comment: @nishyo You might want to be more specific about what "it" is here. If you're saying `break` itself causes the program to exit, then that's just wrong. If you're saying the `return` on the previous line is causing the program to exit and you can't use the `break` there because of that, then yes, but that's when you rework the code.

Comment: @DennisMeng i have edited the post now , i am not using break but i only need the if statement to run once then it should not allow to run inside the if statement

Comment: @nishyo In that case, anubhava's approach would work. If you really didn't want to make another method for this, you could also just pull the `x` outside of the for loop and put a `break` inside the if-statement. (leaving `x` to contain the desired index, or `array.length` if no such index)

Comment: (also, it's generally frowned upon to create a new question if the old one is unclear; it's better to just edit the old question to make it clear)

Comment: i am really sorry i am noob here , i have followed anubhava's approach sor some reason its returning 0

Comment: If you think that your [previous question is unclear](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18445605/335858), you should edit it to make it clear, rather than creating a corrected copy of one. Asking follow-up questions in comments is another possibility, but creating a brand-new question is not a good idea, unless it's completely different.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom method for this:

```
int findIndex(int[] array, int given_number) {
    int running_total = 0;
    for(int x=0; x < array.length; x++) {
       running_total += array[x];
       if(given_number >= running_total)
          return x;
     }
     return -1; // empty array or given_number is too big
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple and straight forward

```
    int given_number = 7;
    int running_total = 0;
    int array[] = new int[23];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (running_total >= given_number) {
            break;
        } else {
            running_total += array[i];
        }
    }
}
```